# Display facet based on users selection in shinyApp

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want my shinyApp to display facets based on the user selection of a variable.

The function that I've wrote works in base R, but my shinyApp is not displaying any plot when selecting the variables. Also, I've checked similar posts, which I've followed but my app is still not working and I don't know why.

Here is the RepEx.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("p","p", choices = names(diamonds)),
  selectInput("q","q", choices = names(diamonds)),
  plotOutput("myplot"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data <- reactive(diamonds)
  p <- reactive({input$p})
  q <- reactive({input$q})
  
  draw_boxplot <- function(data, p, q){
    ggplot(data=data(), aes(x=cut, y = .data[[p]]))+
      geom_boxplot() + 
      facet_wrap(~get(input$q)) #facet_grid(~get(input$Select_unit))
  }
      
  plot1 <- reactive({
    req(data(), input$p, input$q)
    draw_boxplot(data(), p(), q())
  })
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    plot1()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Man, based on what i understood about your need i wrote a simplier code to achieve the output you described.  Theres no need to create the function you made. You can insert input values directly in `ggplot` using `aes_string`.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
        selectInput("p",
                    "p", 
                    selected = "carat",
                    choices = colnames(diamonds)),
        selectInput("q",
                    "q", 
                    selected = "color",
                    choices = colnames(diamonds)),
        plotOutput("myplot"))

server <- function(input, output) {
        
        output$myplot <- renderPlot({
                ggplot()+
                        geom_boxplot(data=diamonds,
                                aes_string(x = "cut", y = input$p)) +
                        facet_wrap(~get(input$q))
        })
        
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your app is functioning, but it takes ~20 seconds for the plot to load.

Second, `input` values are inherently reactive, so including them within a `render` will cause the code within to update.

Here I believe I have the exact same app as above, but much more simple.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("p","p", choices = names(diamonds)),
  selectInput("q","q", choices = names(diamonds)),
  plotOutput("myplot"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=diamonds, aes(x=cut, y = input$p))+
      geom_boxplot() + 
      facet_wrap(input$q)
    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Edit:  As Lucca showed in his example, incorporating a `selected` into the inputs as well as `aes_string` is probably the best way to go.